# How to include text/blob file as resource to be compiled together as executable in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

in Kotlin/JVM `.txt` or any blob files are usually in `source/main/resources` directory to be compiled into jar executable. To compile `.txt` files together with .kt files Kotlin/Native so that compiled executable includes those `.txt`, what kind of

1. build.gradle configuration
2. Ide setting like Idea or Eclipse
3. Kotlin compiler option
4. Steps of commands or things todo

Are needed?

And after including those `.txt` files, how kotlin code can be written to access those text?

For example, in InteliJ Idea project for Kotlin/Native, there is a file `src/main/resources/hello.txt` and code in `main.kt` try to access it with:

```
fun main(arg: Array<String>){
   val text: String = accessResource("hello.txt")
   println(text)
}
```

What's the code of function `fun accessResource(path: String): String` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a task to generate Kotlin code with byteArray for every resource you have. The `immutableByteArrayOf` may be helpful.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  Any direction on how to go about doing this would be most welcome.  What would be the performance cost of packaging resources as Kotlin code?

Comment: I would do something as easy as (in Gradle)
```
task generateCode() {
  doLast {
    new File(path-to-source).text = generateTextHere()
 }
}

```
Next. you add dependencies for the task to make it executed before the compile